# writing to different columns of excel using xlswrite in matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to change the column for each value of j. I am getting error as "Range argument must be a string in Excel A1 notation." Could someone (experts) help me out.? Thanks.

```
k=1;
for j=1:(Nos+1)
    col_fs=strcat('col_1',num2str(j));
    out=eval(strcat(col_fs,'(:,:)'));
    xlswrite(f,out,1,[2,k]);
    k=k+2;
end
```

Comment: The usage of `xlswrite` is not correct. Follow this link: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html

Comment: Also, you can write `out=eval(strcat(col_fs,'(:,:)'));` like `out=eval(col_fs);`

Comment: I have gone through that. But how do I change my column. They are pointing it to 'A2'. I would like to use x,y. Is there any possible and elegant way? to increment column. something that replacing string type ('A2') of entries with (x,y).

Comment: Could someone help me with this.. something that replaces xlswrite(f,out,1,'A2'); with similar to this xlswrite(f,out,1,[2,k]); Help is highly appreciated

Comment: Did you catch the solution?

Comment: hello OmG, I happened to work now only, as it became late yesterday. yes got it. I used the following instead of mapper way..     xlswrite(f,out,1,strcat(strcat(char(64 + (k-1)),num2str(2)))); This might help some others who may be looking for. Thanks a lot. Highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a function to do this mapping:

```
 % x is column number and y is row number
 mapper = @(x,y) strcat(char(64 + x),num2str(y))
```

Then using this mapper instead of `[2 k]` which `x = 2` and `y = k` like the following:

```
 xlswrite(f,out,1,mapper(2,k));
```